# Cannot restore my iPhone backup, iTunes says it's either corrupted or not compatible with this device

Tags: itunes, backup, iphone

I'm in a huge trouble as my new iPhone 4s can not restore a backup of an older iPhone 4s backup.

Few days back i had to change my 4s iPhone which was a locked phone( gevey sim) with iOS 8.1.2, so i created a backup of it before resetting it to factory defaults.

Then i purchased a new iPhone 4s factory unlocked and tried to restore that backup but it failed with an error message telling me that "Cannot restore backup because it's either corrupted or not compatible with this device".

Please help me out because its getting so frustrating for me. I tried almost everything available on the internet but nothing worked for me.